# How to write a dataframe/list into a csv-file?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have written the following code and I want to write the output into a csv file. How can I do this? Thanks for helping me. 
Here is an extract from my code:

```
columnNames = ['Stride Length', 'Stand Duration', 'Swing Duration', 'Douple Support Time', 'Relation Swing Stand']

resultsPerRowRatio = list()

for i in range(len(stepData)):
     stepDataLeft = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 0:5]
     stepDataRight = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 5:10]
     dataF = pd.DataFrame({'stepDataLeft': stepDataLeft, 'stepDataRight': stepDataRight}, index=columnNames)

     #Symmetry Ratio:
     dataF['Symmetry Ratio Row']=np.where(dataF['stepDataLeft'] < dataF['stepDataRight'],sv.symmetryRatio(dataF['stepDataLeft'],dataF['stepDataRight']), sv.symmetryRatio(dataF['stepDataRight'],dataF['stepDataLeft']))
     resultsPerRowRatio.append(dataF)

print("Symmetry Ratio: "+str(resultsPerRowRatio))
```

This is my output:

[image]

I want to write this in a csv file. But I don't know how. I have already tried various options.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Why not ask about the failed attempts at a solution? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, right? See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach to consider using `to_csv()`:

`to_csv()` Parameters(more are available, but this is simple case):

- header: column header, True to include or False to exclude
- mode: 'a' to append to an existing file, 'w' for creating and writing a new file
- index: True to include indexing, False to exclude

**Example:**

```
PATH = your_folder_path
FILENAME = output_file_name

if os.path.isfile(PATH+FILENAME):
    dataF.to_csv(PATH+FILENAME, header=False, mode='a', index=True)
else:
    dataF.to_csv(PATH+FILENAME, header=True, mode='w', index=True)
```

This structure will do a logic check to see if your output file already exists in the folder path you've defined, if it does exist, it will append the data to the csv file without the associated header column names via the to_csv() call. If it doesn't exist, it will generate a new csv file and include the column names as a header.

Comment: Any other alternative method?